# Save output of xdpdump to a variable

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

How can I save the output of xdpdump to a variable. I just want to save the number of packets captured.

```
root@front:/home/ubuntu# timeout 2s xdpdump -i ens3 -w lol.pcap 
listening on ens3, ingress XDP program ID 192 func xdp_filter, capture mode entry, capture size 262144 bytes

385449 packets captured
0 packets dropped by perf ring
```

I want to save whatever value we get on packets captured in a variable. Above example it will be 385449.
How I can do it using grep,awk or sed?

When I used this

```
#!/bin/bash
var=$(timeout 2s xdpdump -i ens3 -w lol.pcap | awk '/packets captured/{print $1}')
echo $var
```

The output of bash -x script.sh was

```
root@front:/home/ubuntu# bash -x d.sh 
++ timeout 2s xdpdump -i ens3 -w lol.pcap
++ awk '/packets captured/{print $1}'
listening on ens3, ingress XDP program ID 1330 func xdp_filter, capture mode entry, capture size 262144 bytes

369588 packets captured
0 packets dropped by perf ring
+ var=
+ echo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var=$(timeout 2s xdpdump -i ens3 -w lol.pcap | awk '/packets captured/{print $1}')
```

or if that first command's output which you show in your question goes to stderr instead of stdout then:

```
var=$(timeout 2s xdpdump -i ens3 -w lol.pcap 2>&1 | awk '/packets captured/{print $1}')
```

Comment: This didn't work :(

Comment: `This didn't work` is the worst possible problem description for any problem in life as it provides zero information that anyone could use to help you solve your problem. In what way didn't it work - wrong output, no output, error messages, etc.?

Comment: I am so sorry. I'll update the question with the output

Comment: Thanks the second one worked :)